# Encountered \ syntax error- java derby

Tags: java, sql, insert, derby

I'm trying to execute this:

```
    String qu = "INSERT INTO CLIENT(name,surname,pin,address,salary) VALUES ("
    + "'" + tempName + "',"
    + "'" + tempSurname+ "'," 
    + tempPin
    + "'" + tempAddress + "',"
    + tempMoney
    + ")";
```

but I'm getting this:

```
Exception at execQuery:dataHandlerSyntax error: Encountered "\'" at line 1, column 83.
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Pin is long variable and money is double variable.

Comment: The first thing I would do is check whether the names or address contain an apostrophe.  The solution is to use a PreparedStatement, which would not only solve this problem, but would prevent SQL injection, a very common security attack vector.

Comment: Do not concatenate values like that. Use a `PreparedStatement`